# Least Cost Path point & polygon QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, vector, point, cost-path

I am trying to calculate the least cost path between a point and a polygon using the tool "least cost path" from SAGA. This tool works fine with the exception that it calculates the least cost path between the point dataset and the middle of the polygon. I need to calculcate the cost path between the point and the edges of the polygon. Any idea how I can work around this problem?

Comment: It sounds like you should convert your polygons to lines and run the least cost path between the lines and the points.

Comment: I think that this question is unclear. Saga's "least cost path" algorithm uses a point layer as "Source points" and a raster layer as "Accumulated cost".